# How to set column width?

Tags: react-native, react-markdown

I'm using the [react-native-markdown-display](https://github.com/iamacup/react-native-markdown-display) to display the following table:

```
## Männer:
| Alter                 | 18 - 25 | 26 - 35 | 36 - 45 | 46 - 55 | 56 - 65 |   65+   |
| --------------------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | 
| Athlet                | 49 - 55 | 49 - 54 | 50 - 56 | 50 - 57 | 51 - 56 | 50 - 55 |
| Exzellent             | 56 - 61 | 55 - 61 | 57 - 62 | 58 - 63 | 57 - 61 | 56 - 61 |
| Gut                   | 62 - 65 | 62 - 65 | 63 - 66 | 64 - 67 | 62 - 67 | 62 - 65 |
| überdurchschnittlich  | 66 - 69 | 66 - 70 | 67 - 70 | 68 - 71 | 68 - 71 | 66 - 69 |
| Durchschnitt          | 70 - 73 | 71 - 74 | 71 - 75 | 72 - 76 | 72 - 75 | 70 - 73 |
| Unterdurchschnittlich | 74 - 81 | 75 - 81 | 76 - 82 | 77 - 83 | 76 - 81 | 74 - 79 |
| Schlecht              |   82+   |   82+   |   83+   |   84+   |   82+   |   80+   |
```

inside this scrollview:

```
<ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic" style={styles.scrollView}>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
      <Markdown style={styles}>{content}</Markdown>
    </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

What I want to achieve is a table with no line breaks inside an horizontal and vertical scrolling. What I get is a table, where each cell has its own width. How can I achieve that each cell inside a column has the same width, without a style?

**EDIT:**
I just found out, that i has something to do with the width of the inner ScrollView. After doing the following:

```
<ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic" style={styles.scrollView}>
      <ScrollView horizontal={true} contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
      <View style={{width: 1200}}>
        <Markdown style={styles}>{content}</Markdown>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

i works quite good. But now all tables have the same width and i want to display different tables each having a diffrent width

Comment: As workaround I'm giving the width to the component, if needed